# Should you end-to-end test code in production? If yes, how do you avoid corrupting database?

Tags: unit-testing, production-environment, dev-to-production

**Context:**

Let's say you have 2 branches, development branch and production branch. 
You unit test the dev branch, it passes, then merge the dev branch with the production branch. (I'm assuming end-to-end tests starting on the server side.)

**Questions**

Should you then run end-to-end tests against the production branch to assure you that the code works in the production environment as well?

If the answer is yes, then how do you avoid corrupting the state of the database in the production branch?  For example, I don't think it's unrealistic that someday someone might write a faulty test that creates/updates/deletes something it shouldn't.

If the answer is no, how would you know whether your code does indeed work in the production environment? I'm guessing simple smoke testing?

**Edit**

I previously misused the term unit test. I replaced it with end-to-end tests.

Comment: well, if its a true unit test then the test should be totally independent of the database and shouldnt even need access to the database to be able to run

Comment: I would neither test in production nor expect unit tests to write to the database.

Comment: All of my unit tests can run on my local machine and dont even need an internet connection

Comment: You are probably confusing unit tests with integration tests. Unit tests are supposed to be testing functionality without the need of any external dependencies like databases or APIs - those can be mocked if necessary so you could test how your components will react to different responses. Integration tests on the other hand would allow you to run end-to-end with actual database. One approach would be to have a separate environment with all dependencies deployed there and you deploy the code from you production branch there first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests don't modify database state, so it shouldn't matter. If you're doing end to end tests, then yeah this is a possibility, but proper database permissions and access control should easily prevent this from happening.

You should be able to run all your tests *far, far away* from your production server. Never run tests on the server directly unless the tests are designed specifically for that (ie. health checks)

Comment: `Never run tests on the server directly` while this is good advice, most company out there don't practice this advice, sadly :(

Comment: Okay I misused the term "unit test" then. 
If you don't run tests on the server directly, how would you assure yourself that the code works in the production environment? (For example, there could be a global library missing that would actually break a few tests that passed in the testing environment.)

Comment: @Kacy you pray to the Internet gods

Comment: @Kacy: You do your best. If you fail you adapt and try again next time, preparing for the exact thing that went wrong. At some point you're either out of things that can go wrong or out of opportunities to try. (Edit: And if you are not able to clone a productive environment then you should work on that)

Comment: @Marvin also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(software)